# Is this foundation properly supported against rotation in an earthquake?

Tags: foundation, drainage, earthquake

This foundation was built 1938, and seems unusually tippy even for the time.  This is in an earthquake zone, the garage has a second floor above, and the given wall is shearwalled and bolted, with plywood on the inside.  Your thoughts?

[image: 1938 Foundation]

Comment: Width at base is 9.5 inches?

Comment: Due to taper it's wider.  Amending diagram.

Comment: The width is 15 inches at the slab level.  It's strongly tapered on the inside, vertical on the outside.

Comment: That's a significant width, especially since the inside edge is anchored by that garage slab. Would it be safe in an earthquake? I have no idea.

Comment: The inside edge is a cold joint (separate pour).

Comment: Yes, but the slab keeps the foundation from sliding, and with that slanted inner wall the top would have to rise significantly before tipping over.